# Temporary Input Redirection in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, input, redirect, stdin

I am looking for a way to dump input into my terminal from a file, but when EOF is reached I would like input returned back to my keyboard.  Is there a way to do this with Bash (or any other commonly-available *nix shell)?

Details:
I am debugging a server program which executes a fork to start a child process.  Every time I start a debugging session with gdb I have to type set follow-fork-mode child.  I would like to use some sort of input redirection to have this pre-populated.  There are other uses as well that I can think of, so I'd prefer a general solution - hence the reason this question is *not* about gdb.

Solution:
**start-server.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cat run-server.txt - |/bin/bash
```

**run-server.txt**

```
gdb ./Server
set follow-fork-mode child
run
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
cat input_file - | program
```

That will concatenate `input_file` followed by `stdin` to `program`, which I think is what you want.

Comment: +1 That explains when I use "|vi -" I think.  I had found that somewhere and never looked into what it *meant.*  This may be the ticket.

Comment: It's confusing when you use angle brackets as if they were quotation marks, since they are used for redirection.

Answer (score 1):

maybe [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) is what you want

Comment: +1 I can see how to have it help me generate a script - I'll look into what sorts of things expect can do.  Thanks for the link.  So far I don't think it answers my question.

Comment: Overall I think expect is a nice tool.  I'll have to dig into it - jbourque's solution was more in line with what I was asking though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an intermediate file? Assuming you want to run the script myscript.sh:

```
INPUT_FILE=input.txt
TEMP_FILE=`mktemp -t input`
myscript.sh < $TEMP_FILE &
cat $INPUT_FILE >> $TEMP_FILE
cat >> $TEMP_FILE
```