# BASH script passing stdin input to a program and giving control back to user input

Tags: bash, scripting, initialization, io, redirect

(I looked everywhere for this, perhaps my googling skill is off today)

I have a program that requires a handful of initialization cmds from stdin (and not through arguments). It'd be nice to move those commands into a script so when the script completes I can start keying the real work. So something like:

```
cat initcmds.txt | myprogram.exe
```

the problem is that the program (child process) terminates after receiving EOF at the end of initcmds.txt.  How do you do this? (Bash, Korn, cmd.exe, csh, all good)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358444/temporary-input-redirection-in-bash – It even shows up in the list of related questions on the right :-)

Comment: wow.  I knew I wasn't the first person with that issue.  Must have been using the wrong search keywords.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat initcmds.txt - | myprogram.exe`

Comment: BTW, if myprogram.exe uses history commands, this seems to disable it.  Not sure why.